# Using wherehas and find function in Laravel is not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have tables called event and eventinfo. Where the event hasMany eventinfo.
I am trying to get the event that has eventinfo with active=1, but it get all the eventinfo whether active is 0 or 1.

```php
$eventsInfo = Event::find($eventId)
              ->whereHas('EventInfo', function (Builder $query) {
                 $query->where('active', 1);
              });
```

can anyone point me where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter `EventInfo` that's loaded, you should use the `with` function with a closure to apply conditions to the eager loaded models.

```php
$event = Event::whereHas('EventInfo', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('active', 1);
})->with(['EventInfo' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('active', 1);
}])->find($eventId);
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but same issue. 
The retrieved eventinfo include active=0 which should not be included as the condition set to be active=1 only.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update the answer. 
It is working as expected. 
Would you mind explain why do I need to add "with" for this case?

Answer (score 0):

In the code in question, just write `find()` after `whereHas()`, so that you can get the Event with EventInfo active=1.

```php
$eventsInfo = Event::whereHas('EventInfo', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('active', 1);
})
                   ->find($eventId);
```

---

P.S.

If it still doesn't work, please use `toSql()` to print out the SQL query statement to check.

```php
dd(
    Event::whereHas('EventInfo', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('active', 1);
    })
         ->where('id', $eventId)
         ->toSql()
);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying with me.
Using "toSql()" is really nice trick to see actual query.